# kafka: Connection to node 1001 could not be established. Broker may not be available

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I started zookeeper and kafka container using below commands in CentOS 7.9:

```
docker run -it -d --net=sup-network  --name zookeeper --ip 200.100.0.140 -p 2181:2181  zookeeper:3.7.0

docker run -it --net=sup-network --name kafka -p 9092:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=200.100.0.140:2181 \
-e KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092 \
-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://200.100.0.141:9092 \
-e ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes \
-d bitnami/kafka:3.0.0
```

The 200.100.0.xxx ips are defined in docker swarm.

But kafka consistently gave below logs:

```
 WARN [Controller id=1001, targetBrokerId=1001] Connection to node 1001 (/200.100.0.141:9092) 
could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

How to fix it out?

---

additional info:

I removed `-e KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://200.100.0.141:9092 \`, then kafka didn't give `Broker may not be available` log info. But why there're so many posts suggest that this line should be added?

Comment: This post should explain things for you: https://www.confluent.io/en-gb/blog/kafka-client-cannot-connect-to-broker-on-aws-on-docker-etc/

Comment: Where exactly are those logs from? The broker wouldn't be connecting to itself. Also, `200.100.x.x` is not considered a private IP space